How to make muffled audio like in lethal company?
I'm a game developer making an online co op game. I want to make a head crab that rips the players tongue out and their voip/voice goes muffled or scrambled like the snare fleas in lethal company. I'm using c# unity and vivox. Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.
Got the voip system done, a lobby set up, and a drivable car.
How would I go about this?

Use the AudioMixer component. Add the sources you want to be affected. Add a reverb slider and a volume slider. Use a script to set parameters which vary the reverb and volume sliders based on factors like line of sight to the player or distance.
